# multiple variable in a struct declaration

Tags: c, sockets

I would like help with know what this means in C:

```
struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;
```

As in, are `serv_addr` and `cli_addr` struct variables of `sockaddr_in`?

Comment: You are right. That's just a C-form declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yap. They are.

Suppose a Following Example:

```
struct sockaddr_in
{
    /*some variable declaration*/

}

struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;

// This means that. serv_addr and cli_addr are varibles of structre sockaddr_in
```

Answer (score 0):

like

`int a,b; // declaring two variables of type int`

similarly

```
struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;
```

Declaring the variable in same fashion ,so no confusion